# uWSGI installed from pip inside virtual env does not recognize http-auto-gzip

Tags: python, uwsgi

Inside a Debian Buster Docker container, I first install `python3`, `python3-pip`, and `python-venv`, which lets me create a python 3.7.3 venv, using

```
python3 -m venv ./venv_name
```

which I activate in the typical way. Inside, I use

```
pip install uwsgi
```

to install uWSGI (version 2.0.19.1 in this case). I have a `uwsgi.ini` file which contains:

```
[uwsgi]
strict = true
master = true
http-auto-chunked = true
http-keepalive = 1
http-auto-gzip = true
http-timeout = 360
```

etc. When I attempt to start uwsgi from the command line, though:

```
uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
```

I get the error:

```
[strict-mode] unknown config directive: http-auto-gzip
```

What is causing this error? Some searching suggests it is related to a missing plugin, but also that the http plugin is embedded in the pip install. I've tried explicitly naming the plugin by adding

```
plugins = http
```

to the ini file, but that results in the error:

```
!!! UNABLE to load uWSGI plugin: ./http_plugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory !!!
```

Comment: You don't need a venv in a container, by the way.

Comment: I know it's not strictly necessary, but it makes some things a lot easier later down the chain.

Comment: What things? Genuinely curious :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [the source code here](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/plugins/http/http.c#L39-L41) `http-auto-gzip` is only available when uWSGI is compiled with the `UWSGI_ZLIB` flag.

You will need to have the `zlib1g-dev` Ubuntu package installed when you install (compile) uWSGI for that to happen.

Comment: Yep. That fixed it. Thank you so much.